# Android: When I run the app it crashes

Tags: java, android, sdk, emulation

Hi. When I run my app in the emulator it crashes, I'm new on Android, please help.

This is my main.java:
http://pastebin.com/UvECkaxN

and this is my main.xml:
http://pastebin.com/GMvE3XGc

Comment: Sorry please paste relevant (small) snippet of the code here highlighting what/where the problem is. Please also provide more information what have u tried / trying to do

Comment: And post your stack trace from the crash.

Comment: hav u declared ur activity in maniifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button `sub` is not initialised. Add the below code snippet in your `onCreate()` method, before setting the `onClickListener` for it.

```
sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I totally forgot! :P

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your Activity `oncreate()`

```
sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
```

Comment: why -1 we will give any reason

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I guess, it has to do with the first line in your answer. As only `sub` is not initialized.

Comment: @R.J accepted your guess not observe add button in activity for that comment only got _ve mark.

Answer (score 0):

you forget to create the reference button `sub`.
you just need to add this below line in your `onCreate`.

```
sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
```